# HTTP error 302 on GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, urllib2, http-status-code-302, http-error

I write a script for automatically posting status to social network from rss. For posting I use just `urllib` and `urllib2` and if I run my script from command line - it's work. But when I upload it to GAE server and go to it's url I have: `HTTP Error 302: The HTTP server returned a redirect error that would lead to an infinite loop.`

So what's the problem here? Why the result of running is different?

Code is now something like this:

```
def get_page(url, post = None, cookies = None, referer = None):
    if post != None:
        post = urllib.urlencode(post)

    opener = urllib2.build_opener()

    request = urllib2.Request(url, post)
    if referer != None:
        request.add_header('Referer', referer)
    request.add_header('User-Agent', 'Chrome/12.0.742.112')
    if cookies != None:
        request.add_header('Cookie', cookies)

    try:
        handle = opener.open(request)
    except URLError, details:
        print 'URL error: ', details
        return ''
    data = handle.read()
    handle.close()

    return data
```

Comment: Almost impossible to say with the information you've given, but I'd guess the unnamed social network doesn't like automated scripts running on App Engine IPs (which are shared with thousands of other applications), and sensibly tries to block them in a fairly annoying way by sending them into a redirect loop.

Comment: Unnamed network is russian network "Vkontakte". It's one possibility, yes. But is there a way to find out is this true or not?

Comment: Please include the complete output of the page, and other relevant code - what calls get_page? Also, you shouldn't ever use 'print' inside a wsgi app.